# Show the output in empty row

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA. i have created triangles which i need to place into the 1st empty row above the given data.

Eg: Please Refer the image.

1) Output after running below code. Yellow marked lines is the row where the output should be shown.

[image]

2) actual output it should look like this . (I have edited it manually )

[image]

I have created triangle for every data in column c. which i have matched to RANGE(I4:AK4),
but as you can see in image, i am getting output in row 13 in actual it should be in empty row.

It is just my idea: As empty row should be used as the output for the given below data.

For Eg: ROW 20 should be used as output row for given below data in column C (C21,C22,C23)

Please refer the code below as i have tried to create triangle but not able to move to 1st empty row to given below data.

```
Sub addshape()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim heightCell As Long
Dim widthCell As Long
Dim R As Excel.Range
Dim i As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim s As Shape

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")

    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 6 To lastrow
        If .Cells(i, 3) = " " Then
        Else
         Set R = .Range(.Cells(4, 9), .Cells(4, lastCol))

         If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 3).Value) = False Then

         Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes.addshape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, 51, 220, 14, 12)
                With s
                .Name = "triangle" & i
                .Rotation = 180
                .TextFrame.Characters.Text = Cells(i, 2)
                .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 10
                .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
                .Line.Weight = 1
                .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                .TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered
                .TextFrame.Orientation = msoTextOrientationHorizontal
                .TextFrame.VerticalOverflow = xlOartVerticalOverflowOverflow
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(245, 144, 66)
                End With
            s.Left = 10
            l = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, 3), R, 0)
            l = R(1, l).Left
            l = l + (R(1, l).Width / 24)
            s.Left = l
            End If
        End If
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Please share your ideas or your codes. 
Will be thankful.

Comment: Why does "Mrz 20" have a triangle in the top row?

Comment: Because ROW 5 is the empty row and i have mentioned that output should be in 1st empty row above. EG: C7, C8, C9 should have their data  in ROW 5 as it is the empty row and same fro the below. Did you got the Example?

Comment: So you can have more than one triangle in the same cell?

Comment: hey @SJR below code worked properly. please can you help me the text in shape . it is showing inverted even after using alignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is loop over all your cells backwards to find the first blank cell above the cell you're working from. Then Align the top to the found cell. Concept:

```
            j = i                       'Using a new variable to start from i so to not mess up variable i.
            Set A = .Range("B1")        'set a range as a blank range will throw an error when used.
            Do Until A = ""             'loop until A is assigned a blank cell
                j = j - 1               'step -1 to loop backwards
                Set A = .Cells(j, 3)    'assign cell to A as one above the last one.
            Loop
            s.Top = A.Top               'align top of shape to top of found cell.
```

In your code this would look like so:

```
Sub addshape()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim heightCell As Long
Dim widthCell As Long
Dim R As Excel.Range
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim l As Long
Dim s As Shape
Dim A As Range


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tabelle1")

    lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = .Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For i = 6 To lastrow
        If .Cells(i, 3) = " " Then
        Else
         Set R = .Range(.Cells(4, 9), .Cells(4, lastCol))

         If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 3).Value) = False Then

         Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes.addshape(msoShapeIsoscelesTriangle, 51, 220, 14, 12)
                With s
                .Name = "triangle" & i
                .Rotation = 180
                .TextFrame.Characters.Text = Cells(i, 2)
                .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Size = 10
                .TextFrame.Characters.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                .TextFrame.VerticalAlignment = xlVAlignCenter
                .TextFrame.HorizontalAlignment = xlHAlignCenter
                .Line.Weight = 1
                .Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                .TextEffect.Alignment = msoTextEffectAlignmentCentered
                .TextFrame.Orientation = msoTextOrientationHorizontal
                .TextFrame.VerticalOverflow = xlOartVerticalOverflowOverflow
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(245, 144, 66)
                End With
            s.Left = 10
            l = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(.Cells(i, 3), R, 0)
            l = R(1, l).Left
            l = l + (R(1, l).Width / 24)
            s.Left = l
            j = i
            Set A = .Range("B1")
            Do Until A = ""
                j = j - 1
                Set A = .Cells(j, 3)
            Loop
            s.Top = A.Top

            End If
        End If
Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks it worked, i have made some changes and it it working as i wanted. can you please help me to align the text in proper way.

Comment: On stackoverflow it is best practise not to ask additional questions in the comments. If the issue in your question is resolved, you can mark the answer as accepted. Any issues you still have that do not directly relate to the original issue you can ask in a separate (new) question. This is to prevent long Q&A or debugging sessions in the comments of questions, making it confusing for future readers.

Comment: OK i will put new question.